# What's wrong with long? Why is subtracting 1 automatically?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, c1, c2, res;
    string str1, str2;

    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        c1 = c2 = res = 0;
        cin >> str1 >> str2;
        c1 = count(str1.begin(), str1.end(), '1');
        c2 = count(str2.begin(), str2.end(), '1');
        cout << (long)(((pow(10, c1) - 1) / 9) * ((pow(10, c2) - 1) / 9)) << '\n';
    }
}
```

For input:

```
1
11111 11111
```

Output is:

```
123454321
```

but, here is the problem,

For input:

```
1
10101 10100
```

Output is:

```
1220
```

Also, for

```
1
11000 11000
```

Output:

```
120
```

I'm not getting why long is subtracting 1 from the final answer if the length of answer is less than 4?

**Note: Here, input string is of length <= 10^5**

Comment: `pow` works on floating point numbers. `(long)` converts floating point numbers to a `long` by truncating them

Comment: Did you mean to cast each of the exponential terms to long before using them, e.g. in a division?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cast variable to int vs round() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128741/cast-variable-to-int-vs-round-function)

Comment: no, just the final result... so that it wouldn't be represented in exponential form

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2044124/1896169

Comment: what is the reason behind losing the last bit if length is <= 4?

Comment: @Scheff: This is not a floating-point precision issue. The calculations the OP asks about are perfectly computable with floating-point with no error. The problem is their `pow` implementation is returning inaccurate results when exact results are representable and are returned by a good `pow` implementation. If `strcmp` failed because a bad implementation handled integers incorrectly, you would not say it was an integer arithmetic problem; you would say it is a `strcmp` bug. So if a bad `pow` implementation causes a problem, it is a `pow` bug, not a floating-point problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Reading your comment, I must admit I have to agree. May be, I have the idea established to hard in my brain concerning "never trust `double` too much". ;-) (Time to re-think and learn for me.)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: This is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which version?

Answer (score 2):

Some `pow` implementations return inaccurate results even when exact results are representable. Microsoft’s `pow` implementation is notorious for this.

In `(long)(((pow(10, c1) - 1) / 9) * ((pow(10, c2) - 1) / 9))`, `pow` is returning a value slightly less than the correct value, such as returning 99999.999999999985448084771633148193359375 instead of 100000. This results in the rest of the arithmetic producing a value slightly less than 1221 instead of 1221. When that is converted to `long`, the fraction is truncated, producing `1220`.

Ideally, enough people would complain to Microsoft about this, or other publishers of bad `pow` routines, that they would fix it.

Given that the problem exists, you can work around it by rounding the `pow` result to the nearest integer (as with the `round` function) or by writing your own power routine to suit your purposes.

Comment: Tested the Microsoft implementation for all combinations of `pow(10, int <= 15)` and it is perfectly accurate. So the problem described in the question can't come from `pow()`

Comment: @MichaelVeksler: Which version did you test? Which version did the OP use? Microsoft might have finally fixed it.

Comment: Yes, you seem to be correct. There must have been a bug in MS's `pow()` which they have fixed, since the code works flawlessly in VS 2015 (both release and debug). So they must have fixed their bug in `pow()`